# Is my frame cracked?

Tags: frames

I just picked this frame up for $100. Is this a crack? It looks and feels deeper than a surface scratch. I intended on this being my 1st build, should I continue? I hope I didn't waste my money
[image: Frame 1]
[image: Frame 2]
[image: Bianchi]

Comment: Steel or Al ? It looks like a deep scratch in powder coating. A metal tube wouldn't (probably) crack that way. Il looks as if somebody was clumsy with a tool.

Comment: Thank you.  Honestly I don't know if it's steel ie AI. Everything I read online about this frame is steel. Still new to the game.

Comment: The starting point is a concern - right on a small radius corner - exactly where a crack would start.  I would suggest treat it as crack until proven otherwise.

Comment: Sand it down and find out

Comment: If I do that I'll ruin the paint right? And then what...? Feels like I'll be in a worse situation.

Comment: You can tell steel from alu with magnets ;)

Comment: No stick with a magnet. Therfore AI???

Comment: You can rebuild a bike that might be crack or you can find out.   Bike can be painted.

Comment: It looks like the material one side of the line is slightly 'higher' than the other.  If you can feel the ridge this makes, it's definitely a crack.

Comment: Apropos of nothing: what is that a braze on for? It looks like it's for a friction shifter but the bike looks too new for downtube shifting. It'd be a weird place and too big for cable guides.

Comment: Just remember if it fails suddenly then your ride comes to a very quick stop, as does the rider.  The condition of the paint is utterly irrelevant if your underlying frame is flawed.  Take it to a frame repairer or a bike shop for a proper opinion.  I think you've been taken for a ride by the seller.

Comment: @RoboKaren for a long time cable stops were separate parts mounted on friction shifter mounts. For example, Trek still had those in Lance Armstrong era carbon frames, and Armstrong sometimes used a friction shifter for front shifting.

Comment: It's possible that it's a deep scratch (and it's also an odd place for a stress crack).  It's in a location where a scratch would be likely, from, eg, laying another bike on top of it and then dragging it off.  As suggested, sand it slightly to see what's below the paint.

Comment: Borrow an endoscope camera, there are cheap digital ones and route it inside from the steering tube. If it's a crack you'll see it from the inside as well!

Comment: @RoboKaren - The braze-on is for a downtube shifter.

Comment: @carel +1 for thinking of cool new toys/tools to buy.   $9 USD on dx.com plus a 2-8 week wait.

Comment: Maybe the question is more: Would you rather bet $100 on it being a crack or bet your life on it not being one?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that is a crack, or at least looks to be with about as much certainty as a pic can provide. That's a relatively common place for cracks to occur, with the thick square-edged boss creating a stress riser on the thin tube.

That the line of it continues into the area where a shifter or cable stop would cover the paint adds to my doubt that it's a scratch in the paint.

Comment: Yes, you can see the surface level difference in the reflections.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to know for sure (unless you have access to an X-ray machine or ultrasonic tester from your side job ... say at Boeing or Airbus) is to take the paint off and see if it's a surface scratch or deep crack.

Since it's a metal bike, sanding it down won't hurt it and if it is a crack, your bike is toast anyway. Aluminum frames can't affordably rewelded like a steel frame.

Update: If you have balls or labia of steel and are willing to risk it (WARNING: STUPID ADVICE FOLLOWS) you could mark the endpoint of the crack with a sharpie and carefully monitor its progress while riding gently. If it lengthens or widens, it's a crack. If it doesn't, it still might be a crack. In any case, it'd be highly risky.